# if my database is empty then showing warning

Tags: php, warnings, notice

If my database is empty then showing the warning and notice messages on my localhost

```
         <?php
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)){ 
              if (isset($row)){
                  $rows[] = $row;
              }
           }
          ?>                 
           Count is: <?php echo count($rows); ?>             
          <?php
              foreach ($rows as $row_id  => $row){
          ?>
```

please help me to clear this problem.

Comment: I added a missing curly brace. I'm not sure that's where it's supposed to be though.

Comment: Try to add an initial value to variable $rows first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the variable `$rows` before your load in case there are no rows.

```
   $rows = [];
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks))
   { 
      $rows[] = $row;
   }
```

If you don't do this, `$rows` will only be set in your `while` loop as you've seen.

You could shorten this to

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all ($tasks, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an improvement to your current code since the post above answers it already.

```
<?php
    $rows = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)){ 
       if (isset($row)){
           $rows[] = $row;
       }
    }
?>                 
    Count is: <?= count($rows) ?> //You'll notice that I changed this line 
    //to a shorter version. since "<?= ?>" will automatically "echo" anything within 
    //it so you don't have to write echo and a closing ";"

      <?php
          foreach ($rows as $row_id  => $row){
          //let's clean your checkbox code here to make it more 
          //understandable
          $checked = ($row['status'])?"checked":"";//This is a ternary operator you can read [here][1]
          echo '<input type="checkbox" id="task" '.$checked.'>';
      ?>               
          <td class= "task"><?= $row['task'] ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Happy Coding